# Kingston RAM and Gigabyte Motherboard compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility, computer-building

To start with, I would like to apologize if it is a dumb question. I am assembling for the first time in my life a pc of my own piece by piece, and for this reason, I often get confused and afraid of compatibility issues I might face, no matter how hard I search on the topic.

My current doubt is, I have **Gigabyte B550M DS3H motherboard** (https://www.gigabyte.com/br/Motherboard/B550M-DS3H-rev-10-11-12-13/sp#sp) and I am considering buying a **Kingston Fury Beast 16 GB DDR4-3200 KF432C16BB/16 RAM** (<kingston.com/datasheets/KF432C16BB_16.pdf>). Although this memory is not explicitly stated in the list of compatible memories provided by Gigabyte -- the manufacturer -- every piece of information I can get from the description of the motherboard leads me to believe that it is compatible, but I am still a bit insecure of it.

Can anyone confirm me if both of them are compatible? How commited to the document listing compatible components (not only for memories) I must be when assembling a PC? In what cases I can deviate from the components listed on those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the list of compatible Kingston RAM in the
[Gigabyte - B550M DS3H Motherboard page](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/model/101319/gigabyte-b550m-ds3h-motherboard).

The part number `KF432C16BB` is indeed included in this list.

So according to Kingston, this RAM is compatible with your motherboard.

Note that there is another similar motherboard model -
Gigabyte B550M DS3H AC, that I haven't checked so
I hope is not relevant here.

Comment: I was not aware that Kingston had available the same sort of list. I had only checked on Gigabyte website. Thank you for pointing that out, I feel more confident with this choice now